# Which default value to use for an optional parameter that is a function

Tags: python, lambda, types, nonetype

I have a function with an optional parameter that is another function. I want the default value of this parameter to be a function that does nothing.

So I could make the default value `None`:

```
def foo(arg, func=None):

    # Other code to get result

    if func:
        # Apply the optional func to the result
        result = func(result)

    return result
```

Or I could make the default value `lambda x: x`:

```
def foo(arg, func=lambda x: x):

    # Other code to get result.

    # Apply the func to the result.
    result = func(result)

    return result
```

I'm wondering if one of these methods is preferred in Python. The benefit I see of using `lambda x: x` is that `func` will always have the type `Callable` for type checking, while it would be `Optional[Callable]` if the default value was `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one fewer function calls by skipping the lambda and just doing a ternary style check like this:

```
def foo(arg, func=None):

    # Other code to get result.

    # Apply the func to the result.
    return func(arg) if func else arg
```

Ultimately depends how much it matters to you; lambda works fine too.